# How to put a link in item with ItemLoader?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to save a link into item with ItemLoader.

Basically I need to transform this code:

```
def parse(self, response): 
for casa in response.css('div.posting-card'):
    item = ZonapropItem()
    item['link'] = response.urljoin(casa.css('a.go-to-posting::attr(href)').get())
    yield item
```

Into:

```
def(parse, response):
for casa in response.css('div.posting-card'):
    loader = ItemLoader(ZonapropItem(),casa)
    loader.add_??? ('link', '???')
    yield loader.load_item()
```

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi again (: you could continue in your previous question.

There are two ways:

- First one is to use `loader.add_value()` method with pre-computed value. Eg:

```
link = response.urljoin(casa.css('a.go-to-posting::attr(href)').get())
loader.add_value('link', link)
```

It's pretty straightforward.

- The second one is to use `MapCompose` which will apply function from argument to every extracted item found by using CSS selector:

```
from scrapy.processors import MapCompose

loader.add_css('link', 'a.go-to-posting::attr(href)', MapCompose(response.urljoin))
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah It would have been better to ask that in the previous question, but I stucked later with this problem. As I'm new in here, I still have not figured out if I can update my questions or not) Anyway thank you very much. Spasibo bolshoe